# How can I stop Messenger bolding from putting * around text?

Tags: facebook-messenger, text-formatting

At some point fairly recently, Facebook Messenger starting making things inside `*` symbols bold. For example, if I type:

```
 *Hello World!*
```

it shows up as:

> **Hello World!**

How can I stop this happening on a case-by-case basis (ie. change it for an individual message, not remove the behaviour entirely)?

Typing `\\\*Hello World!\\\*` includes the backslashes, and `\*\*Hello World!\*\*` yields:

> ***Hello World!***

Comment: What exactly output you want?
*Hello World*
or \*Hello World*\ or what?

Comment: I want the output "\*Hello World\*"

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, then you can marked my answer as accepted answer.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Just simply wrap the word around **backtick symbol (`)**

Like, write 
[image: Hello World]

It will give you your expected output.

[image]